# how to set contentDescription for ActionBar Overflow icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, accessibility

I would like to make my Android applications VERY accessible.

I have been investigating how to set contentDescription for the ActionBar Overflow icon (e.g. the three dots at left hand end of actionbar).

Is it possible to set contentDescription for this actionbar icon?

Comment: Are you talking about the `android:title="@string/my_title"` attribute for the menu item?

Comment: no, I thought every ui component can have its contentdescription attribute set to a string that explains what it is for visually impaired users. it's this field I want to set for the three dots icon used in the actionbar overflow icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content description for the overflow icon is set by the framework, which makes it consistent across all apps. Changing the description from the default would break user expectations and cause confusion. There is no need for you to change the description.

Comment: Thats does make sense, however on some devices i have tested TALKBACK on, the Overflow icon has been announced as something along the lines of ...Image66

Comment: Which devices? If you're using the built-in action bar, this sounds like OEMs may have messed up.

Comment: Sony Xperia Z was the device i used